# this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) always showing false even if all form inputs are filled out

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

```
    validateForm(){
    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
       if (result) {
          alert('true');
          return;
       }
       else{
          alert('false');
       }
   });
},
```

I have used this function to validate form ,but it always shows false,I am not getting what is exact error.

Comment: Including the code for the form for which you're validating would be really useful.

Answer (score -1):

Koni answer deta ka answer . gg gfgfg gfdgf fgfdgdg gfdgdgas feefsdf